# Check if the request is ajax request in wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am trying to reload the pages in wordpress via ajax. What I exactly going to do is, any pages can be hard reload as well as ajax reload. If the page is hard reloaded, then render all the pages as default. But when the page is loaded with ajax, I want to return only certain section of page (ie no assets, css/scripts only data). How can we achieve this?

Comment: You can inject scripts, css, and assets through js

Comment: @HamzaIftikhar is there any way that in page.php to check if the request is from ajax, show some content and else show another content? 
I tried using wp_doing_ajax() function, but it returns false everytime.

When reloading page from browser of url = domain/page_slug it shows not ajax request
and when calling the same page url = domain/page_slug from ajax, again it gives not ajax request

Comment: Go through the jquery ajax docs (https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/). To my understanding, `ajaxComplete` is the event which you looking for.

Comment: If you do wordpress, Please tell me how to pass a custom variable (isAjax  (true/false)) to the page.php. That's all I need.